# Parse errror: version mismatch between Agda and its standard library

Tags: agda

I'm running the prebuilt Windows Agda version 2.4.2.2. In *Emacs/Agda2 Include Dirs* I have identified c:/agda-stdlib-0.13/src and the folders one level below.
Upon loading a module which consists only these two lines, I get an error message.

```
module test1 where

open import Integer
```

The error message:

```
C:\agda-stdlib-0.13\src\Data\Empty.agda:13,5-5
C:\agda-stdlib-0.13\src\Data\Empty.agda:13,5: Parse error
HASKELL<ERROR> data AgdaEmpty #-} {-# COMPIL...
```

Is something missing from the proper installation of the library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Agda is old. See [this page](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=Libraries.StandardLibrary) for library compatibility. You need Agda 2.5.2 for this library.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, András.